# Creating an image within an .net core api without a graphical interface

Tags: .net-core, gdi

OK, I did my share of searching and I have a good memory of what things I would know to hunt down, but have come up empty handed. I have the following:

- .net core API on a really nice reliable server
- the server is my data source for Open Sim projects
- Open Sim servers can take a URL of an image and drop it directly onto the face of a virtual object.

My goal is to use the above to collect information from within the OpenSim (already done) and generate an image (.png is the likely target) using the data. The API is pure REST, but with a command, I'm pretty sure I can write a file to space on the server. But here's where I get stuck:

I know how to create images on a Windows console application and have done so for decades. But I'm not sure how to create a pure memory -> file graphical creation. For that further matter, almost 100% of it will involve fonts. How the heck do you make a .net core Web API aware of fonts? I'm simply not sure where to start. I'll take any advice.

Comment: Essentially, you need to use some library that will do the heavy lifting for you. The one I personally use for image manipulations in C#, `SixLabors.ImageSharp`, has a beta extension that allows to create new images in-memory, including (possibly limited) font manipulation: https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/imagesharp.drawing/index.html?tabs=tabid-1

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be the creature I was hunting for.